# What is the proper semantics for a list as part of a heading?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I have a text slider that vertically cycles through a list of single words. It's a large heading and the list continues the statement such as I do x, I do y, I do z.

I know that putting a `ul` inside an `h2` is not valid, but **what is the proper way semantically to mark this up?**

**HTML**

```
  <h2><span>Oh hey&nbsp;</span>
    <ul class="vertical slider">
      <li>one.</li>
      <li>two.</li>
      <li>three.</li>
      <li>four.</li>
      <li>five.</li>
    </ul>
  </h2>
```

Just a `span` around each word?

**FIDDLE**
https://jsfiddle.net/iraishere/5mtws3po/

Answer (score 0):

When considering markup semantics for dynamic content, it can be helpful to think about how you would approach it if it were static. If you were to write that content as a coherent heading in a static document, you might do so like this:

```
<h2>I do foo, bar, and zed.</h2>
```

You can use that as a model for how to mark up your dynamic content. Consider keeping the same structure and using CSS to visually hide the parts you don't need.

```css
/* add period and space after each item */
.item:after {
  content: ". ";
}

/* visually hide sentence semantic parts */
.sr-only {
  position: absolute !important;
  width: 1px !important;
  height: 1px !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: -1px !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
  white-space: nowrap !important;
  border: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<h2>I do <span class="item">foo</span><span class="sr-only">, </span><span class="item">bar</span><span class="sr-only">, and </span><span class="item">zed</span><span class="sr-only">.</span></h2>
```

The rest is up to you with the javascript animations.